# Performing a LINQ search on all properties of a list of entities without duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, list, search, datagrid

I need to perform a LINQ search on a data set to find all data rows where a search key matches all values present in all columns. For instance, I have a data set such as this in a data grid:

```
    Province        Code    Region
    ==================================
    Alessandria     AL      Piemonte
    Aosta           AO      Valle d'Aosta
    Varese          VA      Lombardia
```

represented in code as `List<Province> tableData` and a search key stored in `param.Search.Value`. In the following code I filter all the searchable columns of the grid and perform a search on `tableData`

```
    if (param.Search != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.Search.Value))
    {
        var columns = param.Columns.GetAllSearchableColumns();
        searchedData.AddRange(param.SelectMatchingData(tableData, columns));
    }
```

I use two extensions to perform the search:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectMatchingData<T>(this IDataTablesRequest param, IEnumerable<T> tableData, List<Column> columns)
    {
        return tableData.SelectMany(entity => columns, (entity, column) => new { entity, column })
            .Select(@t => new { @t, isMatch = @t.entity.GetMatchingValue(@t.column.Name, param.Search.Value) })
            .Where(@t => @t.isMatch)
            .Select(@t => @t.@t.entity);
    }


    public static bool GetMatchingValue(this object src, string propertyName, string valueToMatch)
    {
        if (src == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var propertyValue = src.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(src, null).ToString();
        return propertyValue.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith(valueToMatch.Trim().ToLower());
    }
```

When I use 'va' as a search key the result will be:

```
    Province        Code    Region
    ==================================
    Aosta           AO      Valle d'Aosta
    Varese          VA      Lombardia
    Varese          VA      Lombardia
```

because the Varese row is matched on the values Varese and VA.

How can I improve my LINQ code so to avoid duplicates?

Comment: add .Distinct() somewhere?..

Comment: return blahblah.Distinct();

Comment: Doh! Distinct! Completely forgot about it. Thanks guy. Anyone wants to answer so I can upvote?

Comment: @Eclipse Using `Distinct()` would be a hack. It's much better to not add duplicates in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Distinct()` to remove duplicates. However, although doing so would "solve" the problem, it would be masking the issue with the algorithm: it is better to not add duplicates in the first place than to eliminate them afterwards.

You can change your `SelectMatchingData` to expand columns in an `Any()` condition, avoiding duplicate checks:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectMatchingData<T>(this IDataTablesRequest param, IEnumerable<T> tableData, List<Column> columns) {
    return tableData
        .Where(entity => columns.Any(column => entity.GetMatchingValue(column.Name, param.Search.Value)));
}
```

Comment: Good point, @dasblinkenlight . Thank you, your solution is more elegant and streamlined.